# How can I still execute the code-body of the superclass in a singleton object in Scala

Tags: scala, abstract-class

I think the code below describes my problem best:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Set

case class CrazyClass(i: Int) {

  override def toString: String = s"CrazyClass[ i=$i ]"

  CrazyClass.registeredClasses += this

}

object CrazyClass extends App{
  val registeredClasses = Set[CrazyClass]()

  CrazyClass(1); CrazyClass(2)

  registeredClasses.foreach(println(_))
}
```

This prints as expected:

```
    CrazyClass[ i=2 ]
    CrazyClass[ i=1 ]
```

But if I try this with an object that is extending from the `CrazyClass`, the object does not automatically register:

```
object CrazyExtendedObject extends CrazyClass(4) {
  def something = 2
}
```

The output with the added code is still the same as the above one. If I add a normal extended class as following all works appropriately:

```
class CrazyExtendedClass(i: Int) extends CrazyClass(i)
```

Every instance of the new class will get registered.

**So how can i achieve the same result on an object?**

Comment: `App` plays tricks with initialization (which is run when you invoke main). I'd recommend not using it with the companion of a case class, especially if using default args. That's asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Just reference `CrazyExtendedClass` from your `App`.

Singletons are loaded lazily, so the initializer won't run until you ask for it.

Comment: But if I have to write them out in my code somewhere the registration process is useless. By then I register them myself, don't I?

Comment: Your intuition that it's better not to write code is correct and laudable, because ultimately all software is useless. Class loading is lazy, but there are mechanisms for service discovery. There are also tricks in Scala to use macros to discover implementations of a sealed trait, where what you want "registered" is defined in one file.